# Template specialization for templatized types

Tags: c++, templates

I'm quite new to the realm of c++ template programming.

I understand that I can specialise function templates, e.g. in my case a `toJson`-function template that I want to use using ADL.

E.g.

```
template<typename T>
Json::Value toJson(const T&);
```

where Json::Value is provided by the JsonCPP-Library.

Now I can specialise this for "normal" types like this:

```
template<>
Json::Value toJson<MyClass>(const MyClass&)
```

Great.

However, I have a type, `KalmanFilter<3, 3, 3, double>` (obviously, this is fully parametrised) which in turn has several Eigen3-Matrices as type, who's dimension is determined based on the integral template arguments in KalmanFilter. I would like to specialise toJson like this:

```
template<>
Json::Value toJson<KalmanFilter<int, int, int, T>>(const KalmanFilter<int, int, int, T> ...)
```

Maybe there is a different way of achieving this (e.g. Eigen overloads the std::ostream operator<< generically for all its types).

Or do I have to use a differently declared toJson, like

```
template<int A, int B, int C, typename FloatT>
Json::Value toJson(const KalmanFilter<A, B, C, FloatT>&);
```

?

Comment: perhaps it is better to have the toJson method part of the types you need specialization for?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a differently declared toJson, which amounts to overloading it (which is superior, unless toJson is used like `toJson<T>` which will break it).

Comment: This would help only for the first "layer", the KalmanFilter (and it would be ugly, because it would be rather intrusive... but I could live with it). However, then the toJson for the `Eigen3::Matrix<...>`types would still be missing.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I'm not fully understanding your comment - what does superior mean in this context, and what do you mean by `toJson<T>` might break it? Am I not to provide a default implementation for toJson<T>, because it would catchall other instantiations? I can totally live with that.

Comment: @deets overloading is superior because your usecase can be achieved by it while cannot with specialization (no parameterisation possible there). `toJson<T>(x)` will break because your overload wants an `int A` and not a type `T` as template argument. Calling a function that is user-customizable by explicit template arguments is bad style however, so I guess they won't be doing that. And if you call it on your own, it's not an issue anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve this problem by using a template `struct` and specializing it, instead of specializing a function template, [because of potential drawbacks](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

```
// Hide implementation details in `impl` namespace.
namespace impl
{
    // Forward-declaration of helper converter struct.
    template<typename>
    struct json_converter;

    // Example specialization: `int`.
    template<>
    struct json_converter<int>
    {
        Json::Value to_json(const int&) 
        { 
            // <Conversion logic here.>
        }
    };

    // Example specialization: `KalmanFilter`.        
    template<int A, int B, int C, typename FloatT>
    struct json_converter<KalmanFilter<A, B, C, FloatT>>
    {
        Json::Value to_json(const KalmanFilter<A, B, C, FloatT>&) 
        { 
            // <Conversion logic here.>
        }
    };
}

// Convenient user-interface function, deduces `T`.
template<typename T>
auto to_json(const T& x)
{
    // Instantiate a temporary `json_converter` and call `to_json`.
    return impl::json_converter<std::decay_t<T>>{}.to_json(x);
}
```

Usage:

```
KalmanFilter<4, 4, 4, double> kf{/* ... */};
auto result = to_json(kf);
```

Comment: Looks interesting. A thing I'm wondering about - is this technique extensible? I could live with "no" for my current small project, but I would like to "inject" more conversions to other types for larger projects.

Comment: You can "inject" additional conversions by creating additional specializations of `json_converter`. Here's one real-life [example](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVStart/blob/master/include/SSVStart/Json/Json.hpp#L26-L111) in one of my projects. The JSON conversion implementation is [here](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/tree/master/include/SSVUtils/Json/Val/Internal).

Answer (score 1):

> Or do I have to use a differently declared toJson, like
>
> ```
> template<int A, int B, int C, typename FloatT>
> Json::Value toJson(const KalmanFilter<A, B, C, FloatT>&);
> ```
>
> ?

Yes, that's exactly what you need.

You're confusing yourself by getting into function template specialization. There's absolutely no reason to use function template specialization here. If you want conversions for other types, just add them in the same way:

```
 template<double A, double B, double C, typename T>
 Json::Value toJson(const OtherFilter<A, B, C, T>&);
```

If you have different types in different namespaces, then using a single function template with multiple specializations will not cooperate with ADL. Each `toJson` function needs to be in the namespace of its parameter type. Not to mention that you could potentially be surprised by which specialization the compiler actually chooses to use. Ordinary overload resolution is less surprising.

Comment: An advantage over introducing a class template is that there won't be parallel-worlds. Other users can always add overloads of toJson, creating parallel-worlds with overloads and a class template and its specializations used by the primary overload. When the primary overload doesn't delegate to a class template, there is no possibility for parallel-worlds and anyone will have to use a proper overload.